# Java Can you use a protected variable from an imported package?

Tags: java, import, protected, access-modifiers

Say you have a class in package1:

```
package package1;

public class A{
    int A;
    private int B;
    protected int C;

}
```

You import that package into another class:

```
package package2;
import package1.*;

public class B{
    A a;
    public B{
    A a = new A();
    a.a = 10;
    a.b = 10;
    a.c = 10;
     }
```

All the lines after the initialization come up as an error in the compiler. However, I thought that protected variables can be accessed within the same package. Does import not incorporate package1 into package2?

Comment: `import` does _absolutely nothing_ besides allow you to say `A` instead of the full name `package1.A`.

Comment: No, `import` does _not_ incorporate `package1` into `package2`.